# What version of Minecraft am I playing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I finally decided to go ahead and buy Minecraft. I purchased a premium account via paypal, downloaded the client, logged in, and am at a main menu screen:

```
Single-Player
Multi-Player
Play Tutorial (grayed out)

Options
```

If I press "Single-Player" what version of minecraft am I playing? (Alpha, Survival, Classic, etc.)

Unless I'm missing something glaringly obvious, (and the variety of different minecraft versions is clearly not helping) how can I tell which of the many modes I'm in? (or will be in?)

Comment: Play Tutorial Level was something Mojang was going to add. It way always grayed out. Then it disappeared. No one knows exactly what it was really. It might have been a PC Tutorial World. Only on consoles there's a Minecraft tutorial world.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're playing Alpha (aka Survival).

"Survival test" is [here](http://www.minecraft.net/survivaltest) and Classic (aka Creative) is [here](http://www.minecraft.net/play.jsp). Neither needs a premium account.

---

Here's a bonus chart of what version added when in Minecraft:

```
   Classic    Graphics, Water, Lava, Fog, Mobs, Saving, Clouds (free)
      ↓
SurvivalTest  Health bar, Enemies, Weapons, Finite inventory, Cracking (free)
      ↓
    Indev     Crafting, Dynamic light, Night, Armor, Healing, Hell (unavail)
      ↓
   Infdev     Infinite maps, improved caves, finite water (unavail)
      ↓
    Alpha     Redstone, Boats, Carts, Biomes, Nether, Survival Multiplayer
      ↓       
    Beta      Creative mode, Weather, Structures, Hunger, Experience, Maps
      ↓
     1.x      Endgame, Hardcore, Potions, Enchantments, Repairing, Superflat
```

The Minepedia has more information ([Classic](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Classic), [Survival Test](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Survival_Test), [Indev](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Indev), [Infdev](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Infdev), [Alpha](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Alpha), [Beta](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Beta), [Minecraft 1.0](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_1.0), [Version history](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history)).

Comment: the version number you're playing is always displayed in the top left corner.

Comment: By Cracking I mean you need to crack blocks down instead of having them magically vanish on mouse click.

Comment: I'm crying from nostalgia looking at your "patch note" right now...

Answer (score 3):

**Classic**:
This is the previous free version.

**Alpha - Survival**:
This is the one you have now, the single player is survival mode.

---

[Check the text under the header logo here](http://www.minecraft.net/):

[image: See the text under the header logo]

Comment: It says "une baguette", but your link just takes me to the minecraft main site. What am I looking for?

Comment: Included an image now, it was just a reference where I got my information from.